# Building Android App Chooser with ROSJava

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it currently possible to build [android_app_chooser](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android) from source on fuerte?

Does it use the current build of [ROSJava](https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/) or does it need the JNI-based Java client library?

Should we just wait until the new version of ROSJava is a bit more stable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40940/building-android-app-chooser-with-rosjava/) by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 403 on 2012-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Build from source on Fuerte is to my knowledge untested, however the electric built apps are known to work with Fuerte systems. android_app_chooser uses the ROSJava implementation and uses a ROS script to set itself up automatically. If you want to build it or create your own android app, you should follow the tutorials at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android. However, you should not need to do this if you want to use the applications without modification as you can simply download them from the android market.

---

Originally posted by [tpratkanis_wg](https://answers.ros.org/users/927/tpratkanis_wg/) with karma: 56 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0